# How to get started with airplay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, airplay

I am trying to get started with iOS Airplay (split screen and mirroring) and it seems like there is pretty much nothing on the web about this. I am looking for a sample app or a step by step tutorial to set up Airplay on my app, basically to share my screen, not necessarily audio or video (although I am fine with starting with that its that is more simple).

Can anyone point me to somewhere helpful to learn more about it (besides the iOS library)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [AirPlay Overview documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide), especially the chapter [Enriching Your App for AirPlay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html).

For mirroring, you don't have to do much at all. If you want different content to appear on the AirPlay-connected screen, you basically have to create a separate `UIWindow` and set its `screen` property to the corresponding `UIScreen`.

Comment: I am looking for code samples, since I am not really sure how to integrate this into my app still. can you point to a sample app or code samples maybe? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to read is ["Multiple Display Programming Guide for iOS"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).
Airplay is more related to audio or video than "Multiple Display".

An Additional Window Is Needed to Support an External Display

If your app supports an external device display, you need to create a separate window object to represent the content to display on it. You can show the same content on both displays—this feature is called mirroring and it happens by default—or you can show different content on each display.

Read [Presenting Content on an External Display](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH3-SW1) for step by step tutorial.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:
https://github.com/quellish/AirplayDemo

It shows how to use the airplay display as a secondary screen.

Comment: In my case on iPhone 4 at this point in time, it does not work.

Comment: If that is the case, you should file an issue on the project with details.

Comment: @quellish, i don't play a video. Can i cast my screen without playing video to other TV (Apple or supported) ? Any workaround ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam yes, look at the sample. It does not play video.

Comment: What to do if i want to share this screen to other TV screen ?